# Resetting objective function with CPLEX (c++)

Tags: c++, cplex

```
model.add(finalObjective);
cplex.solve();

cout << "final 1" << endl;
finalObjective.end();
cout << "final 2" << endl;
finalObjective = IloObjective(env, makespan, IloObjective::Minimize);
cout << "final 3" << endl;
```

the program prints: "final 2" and then crashes. No error. Just ends.
How do I reset the objective for my model (I run this iterateively, with the same model each time)?
I would like to do something like: model.clearObjective();
Or somehow remove all objectives in the model, so that I can build a new one in between iterations.

Answer (score 1):

If your new objective function has the same set of variables, then you can use `setLinearCoef(const IloNumVar var, IloNum value)` or `setLinearCoefs(const IloNumVarArray vars, const IloNumArray values)` methods of `IloObjective` object. For instance,

```
IloObjective obj = IloMinimize(...); // your objective's here
model.add(obj);
cplex.extract(model);
cplex.solve();

obj.setLinearCoefs(vars, vals);
model.add(obj);
cplex.extract(model);
cplex.solve();
```

If you add new variables then I would recommend to delete the old model and create a new one. In this case CPLEX performs better in terms of computational time.

Comment: It is much more effective to call setLinearCoefs to set all new coefficients at the same time as suggested than to iteratively call setLinearCoef setting one coefficient at each iteration.